# C++ Thread_local non-static member of class?

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage, class-members, member-variables

I'm trying to have one member variable of a class thread local. However it seems that `thread_local` in a class has to also be `static`..? But `static` would mean that *all* instances of that class share that variable. I want it so there can be different instances of the class, but for 1 of the member variables there is a different variable for each thread that has access to this object.

So how can I have a class object, that can be passed around, and one of its member variables is `thread_local` for this instance of the class (this object), but not for all instances of the class (all objects of this type)?

Comment: Concerning threads, I'm quite paranoid. Hence, when I bundle thread-related data in a `class`, I have thread-private usage in mind. However, it's not impossible to have "thread local members" in a class. You had to make a `std::map<std::thread::id, ThreadLocalData>` to achieve this. (`map` entries are stable - hence, this should work. However, retrieving an entry, inserting entries into map, and deleting entries from map should be done guarded, of course.)

Comment: @Scheff's analysis and advice are solid.  I'll just add that if performance is important, and your thread-creation circumstances are simple (e.g. you know ahead of time that you'll be creating N threads, the `ThreadLocalData` can have the same lifetime), you can have a `std::array<ThreadLocalData, N>` or `std::vector<ThreadLocalData>{N}` member (so contiguous and CPU-cache friendly, indexing using a incrementing `int` you pass the threads), or even the `std::map` Scheff suggests.  Default-construct the `ThreadLocalData`s before spawning the threads, then there's less locking needed....

Comment: This is for a low-level container, I can't use other containers within it. I can workaround with globals.

Comment: OT: Please, specify suitable _tags_ for your questions. They are quite important on SO. I've checked some of your questions and they all had the "C++" tag only.

Comment: Excellent comments above by @Scheff and by Tony Delroy (cannot  @-mention both in a comment, sorry).  And indeed _a thread-local instance variable_, while convenient, does not make sense in the architecture of C++ programs.  Instance variables must be stored _somewhere_.  Even ignoring the fact that C++ stores instance variables inside the object, for a thread-local local variable, every thread creation and destruction operation would have to create or destroy that variable.